# Mule :How to set a variable with part of xml data from the response xml of a webservice

Tags: mule

I have a response xml as below which comes from web service consumer. I want to extract the Response node, into a variable and use it in another sub-flow (Transform message input to add cdata tag to it). The request part of the response xml will be used in the same flow for some transformations using dataweave. The variable is empty when retrieved with xpath (#[xpath3('//GetTransactionResponse/GetTransactionResult/Response')]), since its a node with xml struture in it. Highly appreciate any solution with this please.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GetTransactionResponse xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <GetTransactionResult>
    <Request>
      <Security>
        <SystemUsername>53A5949A</SystemUsername>
        <SystemPassword/>
        <SystemID/>
      </Security>
    </Request>
    <Response>
        <Scheme>
            <Ins>
              <InsReference>200</InsReference>
              <InsNumber>200</InsNumber>
              <InsName/>
            </Ins>
      </Scheme>
    </Response>
  </GetTransactionResult>
</GetTransactionResponse>
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other way to get response in variable by using additional target in your dataweave. And use following script

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
---
Response : payload.GetTransactionResponse.GetTransactionResult.Response
```

Answer (score 0):

Your XML contains is not a valid XML as it's starting and end tags doesn't match... example :-

```
<InsReference>200</InsurerReference>
<InsNumber>200</InsurerNumber>
```

However, if you make  the expression will work as follows `#[xpath3('/GetTransactionResponse/GetTransactionResult/Response')]`

Comment: Sorry, changed the xml.

Answer (score 0):

You can transform the response to json and set variables via json expression.

```
<flow name="xmlparserFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/xml" allowedMethods="POST" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <dw:transform-message metadata:id="864f45d9-f193-4e82-8f9f-f689a2e13450" doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%var response=payload.GetTransactionResponse.GetTransactionResult.Response.Scheme.Ins
%output application/json
---
{
    reference: response.InsReference,
    number: response.InsNumber,
    name: response.InsName
}]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
        <set-variable variableName="reference" value="#[json:reference]" doc:name="Set Variable"/>
        <logger message="#[message]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
    </flow>
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve finally by setting the Response and Request variables in the dataweave as below:

```
<dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
---
payload]]></dw:set-payload>
            <dw:set-variable variableName="Request"><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
---
{
    Request: payload.GetTransactionResponse.GetTransactionResult.Request
}]]></dw:set-variable>
            <dw:set-variable variableName="Response"><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
---
{

    Response: payload.GetTransactionResponse.GetTransactionResult.Response
}]]></dw:set-variable>
        </dw:transform-message>
```

Appreciate all for your time.Thanks!